# react-native-render-html Anchor tag

Tags: react-native

I try to create a function onPress on 'a' tag, but this doesn't work.
My package is "react-native-render-html": "^6.0.5",

```
 <RenderHTML
        source={newHtml}
        contentWidth={width}
        tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
        renderersProps={{a: {onPress: () =>console.log('press')}}}
        WebView={WebView}
        renderers={tableRenderers}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send it to the renderers prop

```
const CustomRenderHtml = ({ html, ...props }) => {
   return (
      <Box {...props} width="100%">
         <RenderHtml contentWidth={'100%'} source={html} renderers={renderers} />
      </Box>
   )
}

const renderers = {
   a: ARenderer
}

function ARenderer({ TDefaultRenderer, ...props }) {
   const onPress = () => console.log('presesd')
   return <TDefaultRenderer {...props} onPress={onPress} />
}
```